# how can I change status bar in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8

In my case, I am using XCode6 for developer IOS8 . The method UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent had been deprecated, but my background is all darkcolor . Can someone help me to fix it? thank you~

Comment: Did you look at the available styles? Did you try the others to see which works best for you?

Comment: Ya!! I Know , I want my **StatusBar** set the **backrground color** to dark yellow....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you can make view-controller based status bar appearance:

Set

```
   UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO.
```

Call

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: I had been used this way to change **BackGroundColor** to the **DarkYellow** I want , But failed.....